# word problem involving time, and square meters

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Betty paints twice as fast as Dan. Working together Dan and Betty can
>   paint, $2,400$ square feet in $4$ hours. Another employee sue, joined
>   their painting team. Working together, Dan, Betty and Sue can paint
>   $3,600$ square feet in 3 hours.
>
> if Sue works alone, how many square feet can she paint in $4$ hours $27$
>   minutes.

I am really struggling with these word problems, I have tried to set it out first but fail miserably!

for example

if betty paints twice as fast as dan than would this equation be valid

$2B + D = 2,400$ ? But how do i include the time element? I cant seem to form the equations for time and work separately, and than link them

Comment: You missed the number of hours the three of them take to paint 3600 square feet.  Where are the square meters from the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that Dan and Betty can paint $2400$ sq. ft in $4$ hours. They can paint $\dfrac{2400}{4}=600$ sq ft in one hour.

Since given that Betty can paint twice as fast as dan, let us take the equation as $p+2p=600\implies p=\dfrac{600}{3}=200$

So, Dan can paint $200$ sq ft in $1$ hour. Betty can paint twice so, $400$ sq ft

Now, Betty, Dan and sue can paint $3600$ sq ft in $3$ hours.

So, Sue can paint $600$ sq ft in an hour.

Now you can easily find the painting done by Sue in $4$ hours $27$ minutes.

Comment: how have you defined 'p'? what does it represent? and thank you for explnation

Comment: Where did you find the three can paint 3600 square feet in 3 hours?  The number $3$ is missing from the original question.  Also you made $p$ the number of square feet Dan can paint in one hour, not Dan and Betty

Comment: sorry it is 3 hours, i accidently didnt type it out, the question says dan betty and sue can paint 3600 sq feet in 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

You should be trying to compute the number of square feet per hour that each one can do.  When Dan and Betty work together, she does $2/3$ of the work.  How many square feet does she do?  Given that she works for $4$ hours, how many does she do per hour?  Once you find the missing number, you should be able to compute Sue's painting rate.